# Play 1.2.4 auto commit

Tags: mysql, playframework, playframework-1.x, autocommit

How to enable MySQL auto commit in play 1.2.4?

I can find the auto commit in play 2.0
I tried using db.default.autocommit but in vain.
Also through code i.e. setAutoCommit(true) but there was an exception while JPA tried to commit the transaction
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PLay will commit automatically at the end of a transaction. If you need to commit within the transaction try something like this:

```
if (JPA.em().getTransaction().getRollbackOnly()) {
    JPA.em().getTransaction().rollback();
} else {
    JPA.em().getTransaction().commit();
}
JPA.em().getTransaction().begin();
JPA.em().flush();
JPA.em().clear();
```